# Linear recurrence analog of fundamental matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Consider the following first order linear ODE:
$$\vec{x}'(t) = A(t)\vec{x}(t)+\vec{f}(t).$$
Let $\Psi(t)$ be a fundamental matrix, i.e. a matrix whose columns are linearly independent solutions to the above equation when $\vec{f} \equiv \vec{0}$.

By making the ansazt $\vec{x}(t)=\Psi(t)\vec{c}(t)$ for the solution subject to the initial condition $\vec{x}(t_0)=\vec{x}_0$, it is trivial to show that we get
$$\vec{x}(t)=\Xi(t,t_0)\vec{x}_0+\int_{t_0}^{t}\Xi(t,\tau)\vec{f}(\tau)d\tau$$
where we have defined $\Xi(t,\tau)=\Psi(t)\Psi^{-1}(\tau)$.

I now want to consider the linear recurrence analog $$\vec{x}(k+1) = A(k)\vec{x}(k)+\vec{f}(k). $$ Again, let $\Psi(k)$ be a fundamental matrix, i.e. a matrix whose columns are linearly independent solutions to the above equation when $\vec{f} \equiv \vec{0}$.

It appears natural to make the ansatz $\vec{x}(k) =\Psi(k)\vec{c}(k)$. We note that $\Psi(k+1)=A(k)\Psi(k)$, so we get $\vec{x}(k+1) = \Psi(k+1)\vec{c}(k+1) = A(k)\vec{x}(k)+A(k)\Psi(k)[\vec{c}(k+1)-\vec{c}(k)] = A(k)\vec{x}(k)+\vec{f}(k)$, whence $\vec{c}(k+1) = \vec{c}(k)+\Psi(k)^{-1}A(k)^{-1}\vec{f}(k).$

However, this doesn't seem quite right since we shouldn't have to assume that $A(k)$ is invertible.

My guess is that the final formula will look something like
$$\vec{x}(n) = \Xi(n,n_0)\vec{x}_0+\sum_{\eta = n_0}^{n-1}\Xi(n,\eta)\vec{f}(\tau)d\tau$$
if we prescribe the initial condition $\vec{x}(n_0)=\vec{x}_0$. Here we should have $\Xi(n+1,\eta) = A(n)\Xi(n,\eta)$ as well as $\Xi(n,n)=I$. Indeed, with these properties, we get $\vec{x}(n+1)=A(n)\vec{x}(n)+\vec{f}(n)$. In particular, if $A(n)=A$ is constant, we have $\Xi(n,\eta)=A^{n-\eta}, \ n \geq \eta$.

However, I am not sure hot to derive it. Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in the smooth case the expression satisfies the product rule:

$$x(t) = \Psi(t)c(t)\implies \dot x(t) = \dot\Psi(t) c(t) + \Psi(t)\dot c(t)$$

However with the ansatz  $x(k) = \Psi(k)c(k)$ we simply have $x(k+1) = \Psi(k+1)c(k+1)$ from which the problems you observed stem from. I one ougth to work with a finite difference operator here instead. But let's just see what happens if we write down the first few iterations

- $x_1 = A_0 x_0 + f_0$
- $x_2 = A_1A_0x_0 + A_1f_0 +f_1$
- $x_3 = A_2 A_1 A_0 x_0 + A_2A_1f_0 + A_2 f_1 + f_2 $
- $\cdots$

Which suggests that $$x_k = \Big[\prod_{i=k-1}^{0}A_i\Big] x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\Big[\prod_{j=k-1}^{i+1} A_j\Big] f_i$$

which is in line with your guess. Indeed if we  introduce $\Xi(k,l) = A_{k-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot A_{l}$ for $l\le k-1$ we can write the solution as

$$x_k = \Xi(k,0)x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \Xi(k,i+1) f_i $$

Note that indeed we have $\Xi(k+1,l) = A_k \Xi(k,l)$ and $\Xi(k,k) = I$ if we interpret this case as an empty product. Thereupon the proof is a very simple induction:
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} = A_k x_k + f_k 
&= A_k \Xi(k,0)x_0 + f_k + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} A_k\Xi(k,i+1) f_i \\
&= \Xi(k+1,0)x_0 + f_k + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\Xi(k+1,i+1) f_i \\
&= \Xi(k+1,0) + \sum_{i=0}^{k}\Xi(k+1,i+1) f_i \\
\end{align}

You can find more details in [this script from Stanford University](https://web.stanford.edu/~hammond/diffceEqSlidesC.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Then it would however appear that we don't have an analog to the $\Psi$ matrix in the continuous case. I find this somewhat surprising, as both in the discrete and in the continuous case, we can find a basis of solutions to the homogeneous equations.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout, to me the results $$ \vec{x}(t)=\Xi(t,t_0)\vec{x}_0+\int_{t_0}^{t}\Xi(t,\tau)\vec{f}(\tau)d\tau$$ and $$x_k = \Xi(k,0)x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \Xi(k,i+1) f_i$$ appear as analogous as one could hope to get. It is just that the variation of constants ansatz doesn't quite work out the way one would hope.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you're right. Thanks!